# Clustering - How to handle markers with the same location?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

In my crurrent project I'm using [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils). I would like to know how to handle markers with the same location when using clustering? Is it possible to decluster them with some offset? If yes, how?

I'm adding picture which shows my problem. Max zoom, no way to see markers.

[image: Clustering problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener` I'm getting all items from cluster and then I display them as list using [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList).